# NDK call Android Multi-Camera API get "Cannot find physical capture result"

Tags: android-ndk, multi-camera-api

I'm working on stereo image capture on an Android device but can't find any examples of the Android NDK multi-camera API. The only reference I found is the test code on [android official tests](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/refs/heads/android13-release/tests/camera/libctscamera2jni/native-camera-jni.cpp). . I am following the procedure for calling the physical stream, but I encounter the error "onMessageReceived: Cannot find physical capture result!"

I don't need to preview, so I create an AImageReader for each of the physical cameras only.
Interestingly, the Java example works well. Does anyone have any insights into this issue?